# Drupal Default Language Fallback

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual website in Drupal 7. It has a menu bar with 10 menu items. Among them I have translated 5 menu items to Dutch. When I switch the language from English to Dutch, only the translated menu items appear. I would like to display those 5 menu items in Dutch as well as those items which are not translated in default English Language.

Could someone propose me a solution or a module to implement the same.

Most solutions are for individual content or entire Menu and not for individual menu items.

Thanks in advance for the help rendered :D

Answer (score 0):

Multilingual menu's are quite nasty sometimes. I suppose you use i18n menu? Then have a look at the following:

Make sure the `Menu link enabled only for the [LANGUAGE] language`, on the menu tab of the node edit page is disabled. That makes sure the entry is shown on all pages.

Also make sure the menu entry is language neutral by going to admin > structure > menu's > [MENU NAME] > [MENU ITEM] and check the language drop-down.